# Display HTML special character > and | in React

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, styled-components, portfolio

I'm working on my React portfolio site & my navbar has the text "portfolio" on the left side.

```
<NavLogo to="/"> portfolio.</NavLogo>
```

It's fine but I want the text to look like this, > portfolio|
But, react doesn't allow the use of > and | characters, which throws an error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use their respective HTML codes:

```
<div className="App">
      <p>&gt; Portfolio</p>
      <p>&#124; Portfolio</p>
    </div>
```

Also, `|` works fine for me in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-http-1hxmb?file=/src/App.js:71-161), event without the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

There are some reserve characters which if directly used might not work as expected.
Therefore you can use the following method to overcome the problem:

1. Use the HTML code

```
&gt; or &#62; for ">"   and   &#124; for "|"


<div>&gt; portfolio &#124;</div>
```

2. Use string interpolation if your project is a react application.

```
<div>{`>portfolio|`}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this code and start with &# and finished with ;

```
<NavLogo to="/">&#8595; portfolio.</NavLogo>
```